# Is there an official source of Google Play Store/Service Framework/GMS? or trustable third-party sources?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, google-apps

I tried to install the three Google apps with the auto-installer I used for my non-rooted Huawei P40 on EMUI 11.0.0 (based on Android 10, I think). Though the installation was successful, there was no response when I click the sign-in button of the Google Play Store.

So I want to try with the latest stable official APKs, but I couldn't find any. Is there an official source of Google Play Store/Service Framework/GMS? or trustable third-party sources?

Comment: GMS suite needs to be privileged system apps. That's why they are come prebuilt with the devices (related answers: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216646/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209870/218526). On rooted devices (or those with custom recovery at least) they can be flashed using third party installer packages like OpenGApps (and many others). But they aren't meant to be installed like normal user apps.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217873 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233835